# mlock and context switching

Tags: linux

A common recommendation is to keep encryption keys and other small secrets in mlock-ed memory.

Unfortunately secrets in registers will still be spilled if a thread gets preempted. Are there ways to ensure the kernel overwrites the spilled data rather than leaving it to linger or do kernels already ensure it?

Does the kernel save registers in the same location each time? I'm mostly interested in linux, though I wouldn't mind something portable.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things that can cause register spillage, from thread preemption as you mentioned to all kinds of interrupts. There is currently no way to prevent this, short of completely disabling interrupts (which is difficult when you take into account NMIs and SMIs) and preemption. This can only be done in kernelmode, and makes a computer completely unusable.

I think the issue is that you misunderstand the purpose of `mlock()`. It is not designed to keep sensitive information out of RAM (after all, locked memory is still memory), but to prevent it from being swapped to disk, either for security or performance reasons. Registers that have been pushed to the stack during a context switch are not subject to being swapped out in the first place. As soon as the context switch is over, the registers are restored.

> Does the kernel save registers in the same location each time?

The registers are saved to a few locations, depending on the origin of the context switch. In the kernel source file [`arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S), general purpose registers are pushed to the stack, usually using dedicated macros. They are later restored using pop. The relevant macros (such as `SAVE_C_REGS` and `RESTORE_C_REGS`) are defined in [`arch/x86/entry/calling.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/arch/x86/entry/calling.h).